# ID watson Natural Language Classifier. Error

Tags: java, ibm-watson

NaturalLanguageClassifier

```
Classification classification = service.classify("<classifier-id>", "Is it sunny?").execute();
```

what would be the argument ??

Where can I get this id in watson?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `"<classifier-id>"` argument is the id of a trained classifier, which you typically learn after [creating a classifier](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/natural-language-classifier/api/v1/#create_classifier) or [listing your trained classifiers](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/natural-language-classifier/api/v1/#get_classifiers).

To learn more, I would recommend reading some of the documentation for the Natural Language Classifier service:

- [Service Page](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/nl-classifier.html)
- [Documentation](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/nl-classifier/)
- [API Reference](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/natural-language-classifier/api/v1/)